# AttributeError: module 'ipyparallel' has no attribute 'Cluster'

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-parallel

I am going through the tutorial to learn `ipyparallel` and while doing so, I got the error: `AttributeError: module 'ipyparallel' has no attribute 'Cluster'`

I uninstalled and reinstalled the package but the error persisted, does anyone have any tips for solving this issue?

My Code/ Issue:

[image: code]

Thanks

Comment: Please never post a screenshot to a code. Try to write code with proper formatting. Thanks.

Comment: You may have an older version of ipyparallel and need to upgrade.  If you read the documentation online, it says the `Cluster` API was added in version 7.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will write and format the code in my future posts. And the issue was that I had an older version, thanks, it looks like when I installed ipyparallel with Conda it installed version 6. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `ipyparallel` version is greater or equal to `7.0`.

```py
In [1]: import ipyparallel as ipp

In [2]: ipp.__version__
Out[2]: '6.3.0'

In [3]: hasattr(ipp, "Cluster")
Out[3]: False
```

Sometimes `conda install ipyparallel` may not install the newest version. Try using `pip install ipyparallel`. After version 7.0:

```py
In [1]: import ipyparallel as ipp

In [2]: ipp.__version__
Out[2]: '8.4.1'

In [3]: hasattr(ipp, "Cluster")
Out[3]: True

In [4]: cluster = ipp.Cluster(n=4)
```